# GIT API to transfer a Repo

Tags: git, api, github

How to use the git api to transfer a repo to another organisation. I get the below error:

> "message": "If you would like to help us test the Repository Transfers
>   API during its preview period, you must specify a custom media type in
>   the 'Accept' header. Please see the docs for full details."

I have specified my headers as:

```
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json"
```

Comment: Do you want to clone or transfer the remote repository to somewhere else?

Comment: I want to transfer it entirely

Comment: …did you see the docs for full details?

Comment: I followed specifying custom headers. Still not working for me

Comment: @abhishekphukan, _did you see the docs for full details_? You appear to be using the _wrong_ cutom header, and the documentation shows the correct one (as described below).

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#transfer-a-repository):

> Note: The Repository Transfer API is currently available for
>   developers to preview. To access the API, you must provide a custom
>   media type in the Accept header:
>
> `application/vnd.github.nightshade-preview+json`